# IMAP APPEND with gmail, treat as new incoming email

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, imap

I have successfully got my nodejs app to IMAP "APPEND" a new message to Gmail, with custom date/time. Everything works fine. But, how do I make Gmail treat it as actual new incoming email? (which needs to be sorted based on existing filters, pushed to spam if needed,etc). Basically all the functions carried out on new incoming email by Gmail. Is there any such event that can be raised on the newly created email, maybe something using its UID? Does Gmail support such functionality through IMAP?

P.S: Using "inbox" npm package. Also tried reading IMAP spec, couldn't understand much. (only got to understand APPEND command part).

Answer (score 0):

No.  IMAP Append means 'Put this directly in this folder'.  You can use the flags argument of APPEND to make sure you don't mark it \Seen, so it'll look like an unread message.

The only way to make it do all the new email steps and filtering is to send it via SMTP.

Comment: Well, SMTP is out of question, as the email I am trying to store have varying "To:" headers (none of which are that gmail account's actual) and all the headers must be preserved perfectly. Gmail does support different "Recipient" and "To:" addresses, but that's a quick way to get my IP blacklisted. Think of this Gmail account as a store (backup) for all the email accross a domain, with the added convenience of gmail filters. I actually did try using mailgun for this, got shutdown within a week as I was forwarding everything, including spam messages.

Comment: Can you use gmails retrieval features to fetch FROM another account?

Comment: You mean importing all these unfiltered emails from the main dump, to another account with these filters? I don't know if gmail properly sorts imported email or dumps them all into a single folder, but it's worth a try I guess. I never used gmails retrieval/import function before.